# Rails posting to Facebook, Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm wanting to give an already-logged-in user the option to connect their 2 social accounts (Facebook, Twitter) in order to be able to post content to the 2 of them simultaneously when an action occurs.

I do not want to have a person log into my Rails app with these social accounts, their account already exists. I just want them to be able to connect to their accounts in order to post something to their wall.

I use Devise for my user accounts, should I use the devise-oath gem for this? I think that gem is designed for logging in with the app and not necessarily posting to the social feeds like I want. However, I could be wrong.

I'm looking for guidance on what option(s) I have, and how it all works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter Omniauth](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter) and [Facebook Omniauth](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) are two good gems for you to take a look at, they have pretty comprehensive tutorials on the repos and if you are just logging in and posting content then the setup is minimal.

I am pretty sure you will need to go to both Facebook and Twitter and register as a Developer for an API key, but I may be mistaken there...either way, I've done this a bunch in a number of apps and it's not a painful process